# How to say "bribe" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, ecclesiastical-latin

How does one say "bribe" (noun or verb) in Latin?

In Italian, it is [*tangente*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangente#Italian), from the Latin [*tangentem*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangens#Latin) ("touched").

The [*Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis*](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html) says *tangente* () means *largitio quæstuosa* ().

Comment: Did you check any of the [online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) for *largitio* or related words?

Comment: Since you tagged your question ecclesiastical, Mt 28:12-13 comes to mind, but the bribery is implied: _Et congregati cum senioribus, consilio accepto, pecuniam copiosam dederunt militibus dicentes: “ Dicite: “Discipuli eius nocte venerunt et furati sunt eum, nobis dormientibus"_

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged this question as "ecclesiastical," the first option that comes to mind is [*munus, muneris*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/munus). *Munus* is a generic word for a "gift" (or even a "function" or "office"), but it can be used for a "bribe," as the linked L&S entry mentions in meaning II.C.

For this "bribery" meaning in ecclesiastical Latin, see Psalm 25 [26]:10, which used to be recited every time the priest performed the ablutions in the Mass:

> in quorum manibus iniquitates sunt; dextera eorum repleta est **muneribus**.

The Douay-Rheims translation has:

> In whose hands are iniquities: their right hand is filled with **gifts**.

In context, however, it is clear that the word means "bribes." Here, for example, is the RSV translation:

> men in whose hands are evil devices,
> and whose right hands are full of **bribes**.

Answer (score 4):

In a verbal sense, Classical Latin would probably have used *suborno* (“I induce/incite/suborn”). For a nominal sense, you could use the deverbal derivation with “-io”, *subornatio*, (“a subornation”, “an inducement”).

EDIT: Realize that both Latin *suborno* and English *suborn* have a somewhat broader semantic field than does English *bribe*, since “bribe” strongly suggests a particularly *monetary inducement*, while “suborno”/“suborn” could mean *any type of inducement* (including monetary) to act in a desired way. In this way, when Luca Brasi held a gun to the bandleader’s head, and Don Vito Corleone assured him that “either your brains or your signature are going be on this contract”, the musician was successfully *suborned*, but certainly not “bribed” as most people today would think of that.

Comment: For what it's worth, _soborno_ means bribe in modern Spanish.